# Why is it a race condition in the following code?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, eslint

I have the following code ES Lint marks as a race condition:

```
const fillPersonPositions = async (person) => {
    person.positions = await getPositions(person.id);
};
```

Full error:

```
Possible race condition: `person.positions` might be reassigned based on an outdated value of `person.positions`.eslint(require-atomic-updates)
```

If I change "person.id" to something unrelated to person object like "null", the error vanishes.
What is the problem here and how to avoid it? (I mean fix code if it's a real race condition problem or tell the linter that it's not a problem if not).

Comment: What exactly is the name of the rule that's failing?

Comment: I can't see a race condition in the code provided. Unless ESLint has more insight (perhaps?) it might be mistaken. Or there might be something else that you're not showing that will actually indicate a race condition. EDIT: wait, I see a potential problem - `person.positions` will be resolved *first*, so you could end up overwriting it. Whether that's actually a problem or not depends on how you use this, though.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Full error: Possible race condition: `person.positions` might be reassigned based on an outdated value of `person.positions`.eslint(require-atomic-updates)

Comment: @VLAZ Firstly I was sure that the error shown due to the next line: await Promise.all(persons.map(value => fillPersonPositions(value)));, but if to comment it out, the error still persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code could be problematic if you called `fillPersonPositions` more than once, and the `id` of the person changed in the meantime. Eg:

```
person.id = 1;
const p1 = fillPersonPositions(person);
person.id = 3;
const p2 = fillPersonPositions(person);
await Promise.all([p1, p2]);
```

Here, there's no guarantee that the first `fillPersonPositions` resolves first, so at the end, you might end up with `person` having an ID of 3, but a `positions` property corresponding to the ID of 1.

Of course, the above is very contrived, but ESLint does not know that.

One possible fix would be to avoid mutation, and instead return (and use) a new object:

```
const fillPersonPositions = async (person) => {
    const positions = await getPositions(person.id);
    return { ...person, positions };
};
```

(It's often a good idea to avoid mutation when possible anyway, for the sake of more understandable code - for similar reasons, `const` is a better choice than `let` when you have the option)

Comment: You are right. However, what I still don't understand about ES Lint error is that if I declare an anonymous function instead of fillPersonPositions exactly in the place it is used, I still get the error despite the fact I can't imagine how it can be called twice: await Promise.all(persons.map(value => (async (person) => {
                    person.positions = await getPositions(person.id);
                })(value)));

Comment: Probably because ESLint doesn't go that far to verify how the function expression is being used - it just sees a function that, if called multiple times, could be problematic. Or, what if the anonymous function was declared inside another function, and that *containing* function was called twice in a row? Then you might run into the problem (and so the linter prompts you to fix it).

Answer (score 0):

The code is marked because `person` is not atomic because it theoretically could be changed elsewehre during your asynchronous opertation.

You can turn of this rule by changing the following entry within your `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
"require-atomic-updates": "off"
```